# Simulating the capacitance of two (perfectly conducting) metal rods

Tags: simulation, impedance, capacitance, software

I have two (perfectly conducting) metal rods (with a diameter of 10mm and a length of 150mm) which i put up (with a distance of 100mm from each other). Now I want to measure the capacitance of the two rods to each other with a circuit. For the environment of the metal rods I assume that it consists only of air. But later I want to bring other, dielectric, materials near the rods and measure the change of the capacitance.

For this purpose, I would like to simulate the experimental setup and look at the magnitude of the capacitance in different environments. It would be nice, but not necessary, if I could also simulate the impedance at different frequencies (~100KHz). Of course I know that my simulation, with this test setup, does not take into account the parasitic influences of the cables and circuitry, but I would like to ignore them for now.

My questions would be now:

1. With which simulation software I can simulate this best? This should be as well documented as possible and perhaps also freely available.
2. Can anyone estimate the magnitude of the capacitance and what kind of circuit I can measure it with?
3. How relate self capacitance and mutual capacitance to each other? What capacitance do I ultimately measure in this experimental setup?

[image: experimental setup]

Comment: Questions here need to be a bit more specific than that.  What is your ultimate goal here?  The capacitance of this system will be *tiny*.  As a matter of physics, you can calculate it.  With care to calibrate out your test leads (in position but not connected) you may barely be able to measure it.  **But why, in terms of engineering practicality, do you care about this _tiny_ value**?

Comment: Normally to measure the characteristics of dielectrics it would make more sense to start with a relatively narrowly separated parallel-plate capacitor since the electric field lines will be mostly straight even without guards and such like, and the capacitance calculation will be trivial.

Comment: Site rules: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: The ultimate goal is to measure the change of capacitance, if I bring other, dielectric, materials near the rods. For example, if I a place a glass of water between the rods I would like to estimate the filling level. Of course I could have made other designs of the electrodes. But, because of aesthetic reasons I would like to use the rod design.